# Prime number Program - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, primes

I, I'm a beginner in c++ and programming in general. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me with this.

I've been trying to write a program that tells you if a given number is prime or not (It's supposed to print "prime" if it is)

Here is the code I came up with:

```
int main() {

    cout<<"enter a number";
    int x;

    cin>>x;

    int y = 2;

    int remainder = 1;

    while(y<x,remainder!=0) {    
        remainder = (x%y);
        y++;
     }

     if (remainder!=0) {
        cout<<"prime";
     }
}
```

The problem is the program won't print "prime" for any number. I suppose there are more efficient ways to write such a program, but could you tell me what's the problem with the way I did it?

Thank you. I Hope it's not too simple, though I'm afraid it is...

Answer (score 3):

Concatenating condititions with a comma will not do what you would expect.
There are valid applications for the comma operator, but in that case,
a "and" is more suitable:

```
while(y<x && remainder!=0)
```

Comment: Thank you and everybody else for your answer. I get it now.

Comment: By the way, I'm new to this website, so I don't really know how it works, but I can't think why people would down-vote my question. I really needed this answer, and I've been trying to solve this problem for a week. Maybe it's my language, but then again I'm not a native English speaker. I suppose I'll just have to be less sensitive.

Comment: Welcome to SO, be warned, it´s rough sometimes ... :/ Sometimes, one just need to have a thick skin here. (PS: I can´t see anything wrong with your language, but i´m not native English too)

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
while(y < x, remainder != 0)
```

to

```
while(y < x && remainder != 0)
```

The logical operator "and" is written as && in C++ (and many other programming languages).

Answer (score 0):

You should make it like that:

```
if(x==2 || x==3)
    cout<<"prime";
else
    for(int i = 2; i < x/2; ++i)
        if(x % i == 0)
        {
            cout<<"Not prime";
            break;
        }
```

Else it's prime.
P.S. You don't need to check number from 1 to x. From 1 to x/2 is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Just one little thing: this code won't work for the number 4, because it won't check it for 2 (since 2 is not smaller than 4\2) It's not a big problem because I can make 4 an exception.

Comment: @miv Or you can change `i < x/2` to `i <= x/2`

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the time needed to test if it is a prime by using "Sieve of Eratosthenes".
X is divided by number less than square root of X.

```
 #include <cmath>
 #include <iostream>

 int main() {
   unsigned int x;
   std::cout<<"Enter a number:";
   std::cin >> x;
   bool prime = true;
   for(unsigned int y = 2; y <= static_cast<unsigned int>(sqrt(x)); y++) {
      if (x % y == 0) {
        prime = false;
      }
   }
   if (prime) {
     std::cout<<"prime";
   }
 }
```

Comment: While this method is useful, I don't think he will need it; considering the facts that he's trying to implement a different algorithm, and even my mediocre computer is able to calculate up to 10 digits in less than half a second

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't we pursue the perfection?

Comment: We should both explain why OP's code doesn't work, as well as give good advice on a better algorithm.